# SQL Server Agent - only email if returned row is greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to configure a job in SQL to email me if the results of a query match criteria.
From the query below, I get 6 rows returned:

```
SELECT USERNAME, FORENAME, SURNAME, LOGINCOUNT
FROM CS.LOGN.ACCOUNTS
where LOGINCOUNT > 900
```

I have configured a job to run the the above and email me the results. This I have achieved with the following SQL:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Alerts',
@recipients = 'abc@abc.com',
@subject = 'CS - Users with more than 900 logons',
@query = N'SELECT USERNAME, FORENAME, SURNAME, LOGINCOUNT FROM CS.LOGN.ACCOUNTS where LOGINCOUNT > 900',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'CS - Users with more than 900 logons.csv',
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@query_result_separator = ','
```

Is there anything I can add to the above, so that if no rows are returned, it doesn't bother to email me? The problem I have at the moment is that I am emailed even when no rows are returned.

Answer (score 1):

I would create another T-SQL step in the job with a query like following:

```
declare @counter int
with query as (SELECT USERNAME, FORENAME, SURNAME, LOGINCOUNT FROM CS.LOGN.ACCOUNTS where LOGINCOUNT > 900)
select @counter = count(*) from query

IF @counter > 0
BEGIN
SELECT 'Rows exist, proceed to e-mail step'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('No rows exist, quit job', 16, 1)
END
```

In advanced tab, make sure that it is configured to quit the job if an error is raised. If no error is raised, just continue to the e-mail step

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: If @counter is greater than 0, how are you going to send the query results?

Comment: by re-querying or using a staging table in both steps

Comment: If the counter is greater than 0 and the steps are configured properly in the advanced tab, the job will just go to the next step, which is just the same as @Christian explained in his question. 

If the counter is not greater than 0, the raise error method will cause the step to fail. To quit the job without going to the next step, configure the "On failure action" in the advanced tab to "quit the job reporting failure/success"

Comment: aghost - thanks, that query worked a treat! Although, I changed the 'On failure action' to "Quit job reporting success' as I don't want to see errors in the job history when * from LOGN.ACCOUNTS WHERE LOGINCOUNT =< 900. Ideally the LOGINCOUNT should never be => 900. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes @Christian, that makes sense. But it would look better if you raised the error where counter > 0 instead in that case. You can optimize the solution after your needs so it's up to you! Thank you for the respons